# Both Bluetooth and Wifi not working on Galaxy S3 Mini

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxay S3 Mini. I bought it from Canada and used there for 8 months without issue. However, when I came to Pakistan I unlocked it, and started seeing lots of issues.

First, I have both WiFi and Bluetooth turned on, but they do not work, even though I have fast WiFi. The second issue is is that sometimes I lose cell service, and can't receive calls or messages.

Comment: When you say 'unlocked it' do you mean `SIM Unlocked` or you `rooted` the device?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. WiFi and Bluetooth modules use the same antenna. This is a hardware problem and I fixed replacing the antenna but you should the check other possibilities. Check this link out: http://blog.brokenlcds.com/samsung-galaxy-note-2-bluetooth-and-wi-fi-problem/

About your second issue, it also sounds related to the antenna of the communication module.